# Is it still "unit testing" if you're using React Testing Library / Enzyme's mount function?

Tags: reactjs, testing

We're currently unit testing our React application with Enzyme's shallow render function. Every component is tested in isolation so I understand why this is called "unit testing".

We're moving towards rendering the component and it's children. You can do this with Enzyme's mount function or with React Testing Library as it never shallow renders. This also means we have to mock Redux if it's a connected component.

What is the name for this type of testing? I've heard it called "integration testing", but when I say this at work people think that I mean something else. Is it still a type of "unit testing" despite the fact that multiple components are tested together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit testing usually means individually testing a specific thing in isolation for example a function call.

What you are doing when testing multiple components together is more commonly known as integration testing.

I believe the confusion may come about as there is another type of testing - End to end testing, which depending on your setup people may refer to as integration testing.

Integration testing could be testing all of your components together OR testing the integration of front end + services.

The stack I use is as follows:

- **Unit tests** - low level using Jest (testing specific functions)
- **Integration tests** - specific component rendering tests using Enzyme
- **End to End tests** also known as behavioral tests, these are more functional and involve testing full flows. Right now I am using Cypress.io for these

If I was you I would introduce some kind of automated E2E testing as this brings the most value. No-one will care if all the components integrate nicely if they then crash the browser

Answer (score 2):

The moment you test more than one component at one go and you are interested in the way different components interact with each others, it is called integration testing

> Integration testing (sometimes called integration and testing,
>   abbreviated I&T) is the phase in software testing in which individual
>   software modules are combined and tested as a group.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing

But just the fact that you use `mount` does not automatically make it an integration test.